# Phone home program for Linux, in case server is stolen?

Tags: linux

I have read the either Windows or some installed software on laptops can "phone home" in case the laptop is stolen.

So I was wondering, if something like that exist for Linux, so I can install that on my servers, in case they are stolen, and the thieves are so stupid to put them online =)

Comment: Servers and laptops are worlds apart. The first, and possibly most important, step in securing your servers is physical security. "Phone home" software is gone once the server has been wiped ready for reuse or sale. I can't imagine anyone stealing a server and not wiping it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [prey](http://preyproject.com/). It's multiplatform and can do things like autoconnect to wifi, geolocate the laptop and even take pictures if there's a camera.

I guess there would be no problem to install them on servers :), it is supposed to be lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

A simple script that to a "surf" to webserver every hour or so.

Then the server can store the clients id / hostname and ip-number etc etc.

And if the servers are stolen you would at least get the new ip number that was used for the servers to be connected to the web.

This is kind of script is simple to do, but the real question is what you will do with this information in a real situation? How do you find out what physical address is connected to that ip-number? Will the police help you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any software can really help you in case your laptop/server was stolen, because an the chance "thieves are so stupid to put them online" not so big, plus it can be no wired/wireless/phone network available, plus your box can be sold by pieces few hours ago it was stolen.

So if your box(server/desktop/laptop) is really valuable for you, it should be better to build-in GPS module. It's very small, cheap, can fit into laptop case and can provide your device watching via satellite.